# Parallel dot plot for repeated measures with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to try to recreate this graphic for repeated measures: [parrellel dot plot](http://www.gigawiz.com/images13/paradotplot1.jpg) in R using ggplot2. I'm not so concerned about the p-value text.

As a dataset, I'm playing around with the epilepsy data set in the robustbase package. This dataset has a single baseline measurement "Base4" and four after treatment measurements for two treatments (equivalent to group number in the linked images).

Any ideas?

EDITED EDIT:
Since code and an attempt was requested here's where I'm at:

```
library(robustbase)

help(epilepsy)

attach(epilepsy)

names(epilepsy)

table(Trt)

epil<-melt(epilepsy[,c(1,11,2,3,4,5,8)], id=c("ID", "Trt"))

ggplot(epil, aes(x=variable, y=value))+geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", binwidth = .5,stackdir = "centerwhole")
```

The issue would be drawing lines between each dot for each individual ID. I think I can figure out how to color them by treatment.

I understand this plot may be a bit busy, but my goal in this to try to come up with a good plot that shows the repeated measures aspect of this study.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: This really appears too busy and meaning is likely lost.  While I believe this is possible with ggplot2 I wonder if a different approach may be better.  Perhaps faceting by group.  Several meaningful plots may be more powerful than a single complex plot.  In any event sample and attempted code is a prerequisite for help.

Comment: Changes have been made. Sample and attempted code now present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like

```
epil[epil$variable == "Base4", "dot.group"] <- "before"
epil[epil$variable != "Base4", "dot.group"] <- "after"
ggplot(epil, aes(x=dot.group, y=value))+geom_path(aes(color = variable, group = factor(ID)))+geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", binwidth = .5,stackdir = "centerwhole")
```

The colors come out a little bit wonky.

Comment: Ah yes. That seemed to do it. Although I wanted the colors of the line to be related to treatment Progabibe/placebo. Based on your suggestion here's what I went with:

ggplot(epil, aes(x=variable, y=value+1))+
  
geom_path(aes(color = Trt, group = factor(ID)))+
  
geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", binwidth = .1,stackdir = "centerwhole") + 
  
scale_y_continuous(trans=log2_trans())

Comment: Ah, good.  I was messing around trying to color the line based on the "variable" in the "after" group, but couldn't quite get it to work cleanly.